# Exclude some text fields in MongoDB text index

Tags: mongodb, full-text-indexing, nosql

I have a collection that has a text index like this:

```
db.mycollection.createIndex({ "$**" : "text"},{ "name" : "AllTextIndex"}))
```

The collection's documents have many text data blocks. I want to exclude some of them in order to not get results that includes text matched from the excluded blocks.

However, **I don't want to define each field in the text index** like below in order to exclude the, for example, `NotTextSearchableBlock` block:

```
db.application.ensureIndex({
    "SearchableTextBlock1": "text",
    "SearchableTextBlock2": "text",
    "SearchableTextBlock3": "text"
})
```

Here is a document example:

```
{
      "_id": "e0832e2d-6fb3-47d8-af79-08628f1f0d84",
      "_class": "com.important.enterprise.acme",
      "fields": {
        "Organization": "testing"
      },
      "NotTextSearchableBlock": {
        "something": {
          "SomethingInside": {
           "Text":"no matcheable text"
          }
        }
      },
      "SearchableTextBlock1": {
        "someKey": "someTextCool"
      },
      "SearchableTextBlock2": {
        "_id": null,
        "fields": {
          "Status": "SomeText"
        }
      },
      "SearchableTextBlock3": {
        "SomeSubBlockArray": [
          {
            "someText": "Pepe"
          }
        ]
      }
}
```

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, **there is no documented way to *exclude* certain fields from a text index.** (See [Text Indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/) in mongodb's documention.)

As you already know:

When establishing a `text` index, you have to identify the specific text field(s) to index. The field must be a string or an array of string elements.

```
db.mycollection.createIndex({
    mystringfield : "text"
    mystringarray : "text"
})
```

You may also index **all** text found within a collection's documents by using the wildcard specifier `$**`.

```
db.mycollection.createIndex(
   { "$**" : "text" },
   { name : "mytextindex" }
)
```

Comment: I think it should be an enhancement for this feature of mongo, because some documents can has a lot of text, so you could want, like me, but only avoid some sub set of the document, i think I have to exclude this block in the search query, not by the text index

Comment: This kind of sucks.  mongo will allow creation of a wildcard index, but since their is a unique index on userId it will not allow such an index. 

db.users.createIndex( { firstName: "text", "lastName": "text",  "userId": "text", "address.zip": "text"  }, 
    {default_language: "english" })

Comment: The annoyance for me is that once the text index is created you have to search the entire bloody thing and are unable to specify the field you wish to query... Also it seems you can only create 1 text index. I'm wondering if its possible to manipulate the results afterward using the weighting system but this feels like a dirty solution